# VTK 7.0.0 vtkRenderingOpenGL2 not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, vtk

for a few days (yeah I know) I've been trying to install VTK 7.0.0 on my 64-Bit Windows 7 machine.
These are the steps I took:

Downloaded VTK-7.0.0

Started CMake 3.7.0 - GUI

(Qt 5.7.0 is already downloaded and installed)

Configured VTK with Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64

(configured until no entries where marked red)

(VTK_Rendering_Backend is set to OpenGL2, everything is configured to work with QT5)
Generated

Opened Project in Visual Studio 2015

Select ALL_BUILD -> Build

Errors:

> Fehler MSB6006    "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code -1073741515 beendet.
>   vtkRenderingOpenGL2 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
>   Fehler  LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkRenderingOpenGL2-7.0.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. vtkGUISupportQt C:\VTK\GUISupport\Qt\LINK
>   Fehler  MSB6006 "cmd.exe" wurde mit dem Code -1073741515 beendet.   vtkRenderingLICOpenGL2  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
>   Fehler  LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkGUISupportQt-7.0.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. vtkRenderingQt  C:\VTK\Rendering\Qt\LINK
>   Fehler  LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkGUISupportQt-7.0.lib" kann nicht geöffnet werden. vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL   C:\VTK\GUISupport\QtOpenGL\LINK 1

Translated:

> Error MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515  vtkRenderingOpenGL2 C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
>   Error   LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkRenderingOpenGL2-7.0.lib" could not be opened.    vtkGUISupportQt C:\VTK\GUISupport\Qt\LINK
>   Error   MSB6006 "cmd.exe" exited with code -1073741515  vtkRenderingLICOpenGL2  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets
>   Error   LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkGUISupportQt-7.0.lib" could not be opened.    vtkRenderingQt  C:\VTK\Rendering\Qt\LINK
>   Error   LNK1104 Datei "....\lib\Debug\vtkGUISupportQt-7.0.lib" could not be opened.    vtkGUISupportQtOpenGL   C:\VTK\GUISupport\QtOpenGL\LINK

I really don't know, where I went wrong. Did i configure it right?

Comment: check your paths - are the libraries that VTK is looking for on them?

Comment: All of the paths are correct

Comment: Do you have spaces in your path? qmake doesn't like it.